# Store reference to WPF element in view model object with MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I use the **MVVM pattern** to provide data to a user control in a window.
I would like to implement a **method on the view model** object which **forwards any calls** to itself to the **corresponding user control**, that it supplies with data. For this I would need to have a **reference to the control** in the view model object.

I could do this by declaring a property on the user control that returns a reference to the control itself, and then bind to the view model object, but it's quite ugly:

```
<MyUserControl ReferenceToMyself="{Binding CorrespondingUserControl, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

*And then in the view model object:*

```
public void MethodThatForwardsCalls() => CorrespondingUserControl.ThisIsCalled();
```

Is there a better way to **bind a control itself to a view model object**?

Comment: Do not do that! If you need to notify the view of something or invoke a method in response to an event happening elsewhere then look at using an event aggregator pattern that allows you to publish and subscribe to events.

Comment: @slugster Thank you, I haven't heard so far about the event aggregator pattern, it was worth checking out! I'm not sure which solution I'm going to use, but it was a worthy info, +1 goes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you instead considered using an event-like interaction between the ViewModel and the View to avoid having to keep references of the View in the ViewModel?

In the ViewModel, I would create a property of type `Action` and call it something like `ThisIsCalledEvent`;

```
#region ThisIsCalledEvent
        private Action m_ThisIsCalledEvent;
        public Action ThisIsCalledEvent
        {
            get
            {
                return m_ThisIsCalledEvent;
            }
            set
            {
                if (m_ThisIsCalledEvent != value)
                {
                    m_ThisIsCalledEvent = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ThisIsCalledEvent));
                }
            }
        }

#endregion
```

Then, in `MyUserControl`, add an event callback to the `DataContextChanged` event;

`this.DataContextChanged += MyUserControl_DataContextChanged;` in the CS constructor, or
`DataContextChanged="MyUserControl_DataContextChanged"` in the XAML constructor.

Now, in the event callback, you can set the `Action` for the `ThisIsCalledEvent` property of the ViewModel;

```
private void MyUserControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControlViewModel vm = DataContext as MyUserControlViewModel; //Get the ViewModel from the View's DataContext

    if(vm == null)
        return;

    vm.ThisIsCalledEvent = delegate () { ThisIsCalled(); }; //When the action is invoked, call the desired function
}
```

Now, back to the ViewModel, to invoke you simply change your method's body to;

```
public void MethodThatForwardsCalls()
{
    this.ThisIsCalledEvent?.Invoke(); //Invoke the Action, if it exists, that has been set by the View
}
```

This way, you never keep an instance of the View in the ViewModel, and each time a new view is instantiated from the ViewModel, it sets the `Action` callback.

**EDIT**
As suggested by Jürgen Röhr in the comments, in the `DataContextChanged` event callback, you can use the `args.NewValue` to bind to the new DataContext. Furthermore, if you register the delegate to the `Action` property in addition instead of setting it, you can use `args.OldValue` to de-register it from the previous DataContext.

Comment: Good one. Just use the `args` parameter in `MyUserControl_DataContextChanged` to register to `NewValue.ThisIsCalledEvent` and deregister from 'OldValue.ThisIsCalledEvent'.

Comment: Mark Diedericks thank you, this solution definitely solves the problem. Actually the **event aggregator pattern** mentioned by _slugster_ in their answer is a more elegant approach, for my case I found this way of solving it useful.

Comment: @JürgenRöhr thank you for your very important comment, this is even not only a subtle thing, args.OldValue is very useful for unsubscribing from an event, which prevents the occurrance of memory leaks!